# How to create a continuous animation in iOS which will also run when app in background?

Tags: ios, core-animation

I am creating a game in which i have to move coveyner belt continuously from top to bottom.The problem arises when my app goes into background and is resumed later.

The object is removed from  current position, and the animation stops.

Comment: What (if anything at all) have you tried to restore the animation?

Comment: No the animations will not play in background. You will have to save the state of the objects when the app goes to background and then restore the states of the objects when application comes to foreground.

Comment: It is impossible to answer without seeing code but, I suspect what is happening is that the view is being unloaded and your view controller does not reload it correctly - specifically it needs to reload the conveyer belt and its animations. Behaviour is also dependent on OS See "Memory management" here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: i have used the Apple's  recommendation to pause and resume animation?but when my app goes into background all layer from current position is removed when app switched back to foreground.

Comment: Is there any body who ever created a conveyner belt animation in iOS?if yes plz provided link or resource for that.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments are describing you basically can't do it, at least not in an strait-forward way.
Let me show you how I would approach the following problem:

The main problem that you have is that when an object is being animated the actual position of the object doesn't really change. What changes is the presentation layer instead!
So, how can you know where the objects are exactly? Well, theoretically you can do so the by asking the layers presentation layer for the actual frame, anchorpoint, or whatever property it is that you are animating:

```
 [[myView.layer presentationLayer] frame];
```

So, what I would do is when the application goes to background I would set update all the views to reflect the presentation layer. When you come back, I would resume the animations from there. The objects should be in the right place.

```
 NSAarray *viewsBeingAnimated;

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
 for (UIView *oneView in viewBeingAnimated){
    // Update whatever other properties that you were animating
    [oneView setFrame:[[myView.layer presentationLayer] frame]];

    [oneView layer] removeAllAnimations];
  } 
}
```

Now, once the app has resumed, you should be able to continue from there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)pauseLayer:(CALayer*)layer{   
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
layer.speed = 0.0;
layer.timeOffset = pausedTime;}

#pragma mark -resume game

-(void)resumeLayer:(CALayer*)layer{   
NSLog(@"paused:%f",[layer timeOffset]);
CFTimeInterval pausedTime = [layer timeOffset];
layer.speed = 1.0;
layer.timeOffset = 0.0;
layer.beginTime = 0.0;
CFTimeInterval timeSincePause = [layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - pausedTime;
layer.beginTime = timeSincePause;}
```

I am using this code and i'm using block based animation to animate thousands of image-one at time falling from top to bottom of iPhone screen